# Search and delete to end of line in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to clean up some code and I am trying to find a good way of achieving the following:

```
I am a #decent
guy
```

and I want:

```
I am a guy
```

I tried using

```
:g/#/d
```

but the whole line gets deleted and I only want to delete until the end of line. What is the best way to achieve this in vim?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That won't because the usage of that command:

`:[range]g/pattern/cmd`

defaults to range being the whole line, and you are not doing any substitution anyway.

---

Use:

```
:%s/#.\+\n//g
```

instead.

- `#` Matches a literal #.
- `.\+\n` Matches everything until the end of line, and a new line.
- `//` Replaces the entire match with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

With `:global` you would want something like

```
:global/#/normal! f#D | join
```

or

```
:global/#/substitute/#.*// | join
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
:s/ # .*\n/ /
```

Explanation:

You were using the wrong command, as they may look similar to new users.

- `:[range]g/VRE/act` Globally apply the "act"ion (one letter command) to all lines (in range, default all file) matching the VRE (pattern)
- `:[range]s/VRE/repl/f` Substitute within lines (in range, default current line) the matching VRE (pattern) with the "repl"acement using optional "f"lags

Now about the pattern, I think this candidate cover most cases (all but comments at the beginning of a line and comments without space after pound sign)

- `#` litteral space, then hash tag, then space again
- `.*` dot for any character, star to mean the previous may occur many times or even be absent
- `$` dollar at end to stay at "end of line", but `\n` to catch en EOL here

Comment: Actually, theyre not POSIX BREs. They’re vim patterns, and they have some unique features. See `:help pattern`.

Comment: ViM like others has a superset of Bill's original Vi and hence inherit Ed regex. This former is the base of POSIX BREs even if they lake of classes (stuff added laterly) That's why I mention them as BRE. Many implementations are really close to BRE (and having extra feature doesn't mean fondamental features can't be used.) For ViM, differences are discussed here https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4505/28771

Comment: However, as ViM has feature that make it work sometimes a bit like ERE (i.e. magic or not), you are right: I should simply call that VRE (will edit my answer that way in a while) Anyway, the proposed pattern works.

Answer (score 0):

press `d` + `shift 4` or `d` + `$`, which means delete to end of the line

- `d` means delete
- `shift 4` or `$` means cursor to end of the line